# How to create html pages which don't change very much and not very often?

Tags: html, ruby, ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails server that connects to a json API on another server to get data to build the pages dynamically. These pages, however, don't change very much and not very often.

I was thinking I could cut down the page load time, also, cut down the calls to the JSON API significantly if I just periodically called the JSON API and wrote the html files as static html pages. What is a way for building the html files in ruby / rails from scratch?

Comment: You should look into [Rails caching](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html) options. Most likely the best way to get the results you want without interfering too much with the Rails architecture and workflow.

Comment: btw: I disagree with this question being "too broad". My comment is already large part of the answer and a full answer how to implement a simple caching scheme would be just a few sentences.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want to do would be possible by using render_to_string and saving the result into a file. Then your controller could use this file. But it is somewhat cumbersome.

Using caching would automate this process and allow more detailed control about what part of a page is cached. Also you would not have to change much of the existing code, since the caching mechanism nicely fits into the Rails workflow.

Details are explained here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html

There are many different strategies possible and different levels of either caching parts of a page or even the return values of single methods. Depending on what part of the page is static and where exactly is the bottleneck (more often methods that access the database or an external API, less likely the rendering itself).

So you could maybe use fragment caching. Assuming your page as some partial that renders the content you got from an API call this would look something like this:

```
<% cache(action: 'api_stuff') do %>
  <h1>that's it:</h1>
  <% api_source.get_data.each do |line| %>
    <%# render a line of data %>
    <%# or render a partial %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

This has the slight disadvantage that you need to make the api call from the view code. Not exactly the most elegant way. Rails caching is somewhat expecting ActiveRecord objects.

So you may prefer another approach and instead manually use the Rails cache. In this case the class that provides the API access would work like this:

```
def get_data()
    Rails.cache.fetch("some_unique_id") do
      make_api_call() # if cache fails actually retrieve from API
    end
  end
```

That way Rails will try to find the data in the cache named "some_unique_id". If this fails (does not exist, was deleted or expired) it will call make_api_call() to get the data.

You can either manually delete or expire the cache (just write some script) or add an expiration interval:

```
Rails.cache.fetch("some_unique_id", expires_in: 24.hours) do
```

Manu more variations are possible. In addition you can decide where the cache is stored, files, memory or memcached are just some of the options here.

Comment: +1 render_to_string seems like the easiest solution. from there i can just skip the caching, since the file should be read straight from the public directory. right?

Comment: @kurtybot yes, would be one way. there is a thing called response.body which also would have the result of an action rendering (can be used in an actions after_filter). To render a static file something like `render file: 'public/filename.html'` should work.